# Error casting CHAR(1) SQL column as "char" in code

Tags: c#, sql, .net, type-conversion

I'm selecting from a SQL Server 2000 box `CHAR(1)` column called `Combo_Label` - it will always have a single `A`..`Z` character in there. During testing, it will convert the first 70 or so items with no problem, but then runs into a `Invalid Cast Exception`.

This is the problem line:

```
char comboLabel = (char)formCombo.Rows[j]["Combo_Label"];
```

This is a screenshot of the watch list showing some ways it can be evaluated.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYQcN.png]

Any thoughts as to why this occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database and the Db access APIs have no concept of `char`. Your `CHAR(1)` is mapped to `string`.

probably the most sensible option:

```
  string comboLabel = (string)formCombo.Rows[j]["Combo_Label"];
```

but if you really want a `char` :

```
  char comboLabel = ((string)formCombo.Rows[j]["Combo_Label"])[0];
```

Comment: Gotcha - works well. Do you know why it would work for the first 71 rows, and then have the casting error occur? Is that something behind the scenes/internals?

Comment: I would guess the first 70 contain NULL. Take a good look at the data.

Answer (score 0):

The field is a string , you can do something like that but also need to consider if hte field is null or an emmpty string

`char comboLabel = ((string)formCombo.Rows[j]["Combo_Label"])[0];`

Answer (score 0):

first convert that to a **string**, then get first character...

```
char comboLabel = formCombo.Rows[j]["Combo_Label"].ToString()[0];
```