# Inserting c# char variable data to ADO Char(1) field

Tags: c#

I am experiencing this rather weird decimal addition to my char value during the conversion.
[image]

Tried the following conversion but the decimal value just keeps on getting assigned along with the char to the variable:

1. `Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());`
2. `Console.ReadLine().ToString()[0];`
3. `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;`

Object containing char field:
[image: objekt]

Schema:

[image: Daten]

Error @ DAL : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'String or binary data would be truncated.

USING : .NET Standard Libs

Comment: Got the solution to the problem over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941023/error-casting-char1-sql-column-as-char-in-code)!

Answer (score 5):

Your char is just displayed with the decimal value before it. So the decimal value is the ASCII value of the character. You could easily test this by printing the value and you'd see that it only contains the character. If you want to test it while debugging, I'd suggest using `employeeGrade.ToString()` in the watch windows.

It wouldn't even be possible for a char to hold the value *90'Z'* because it would be multiple characters. You can see the ASCII values in a ASCII table like this: http://ascii.cl/.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid that decimal value ? I am sending the values to my DAL to add it to my database, but the db just rejects that value

Comment: Is the column in the db a char? because it actually should save the character (here the 'Z') only.

Comment: Or maybe your db is displaying as well the ASCII value and the char but actually containing just the char itself. you could test this as well by getting the value again and printing it.

Comment: @Manti_Core : Its decimal representation is displayed _**in the debugger only**_, in order to help you identify which character it is _(see the [**`DebuggerDisplay` attribute**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx))_. When you use it in-code it will just be a `Z`, so the reason your DB rejects it is related to something else.

Comment: the char field is a part of an _employee_ object and yes the field in _db_ is also a char and I am able to retrieve and display the records using _List<T>_

Comment: @VisualVincent I am passing the object around different layers and the decimal value is just passed along with the char upto the data access layer which rejects the value by giving me this `String or binary data would be truncated`

Comment: @Manti_Core : I am 100% certain that the decimal value _**IS NOT**_ passed along with it. It is merely a way of displaying it in the debugger so you can more easily check what char it is (for non-alphabetic characters). -- **I assure you, it's something else that is causing the issues.** -- Microsoft could've given it the attribute: `[DebuggerDisplay("This isn't a char")]` and every char in the debugger would've said `This isn't a char`. That doesn't make its value such.

Comment: @Manti_Core "which rejects the value" -- How have you determined that it's *that* value that's rejected, and not one of the other values?

Comment: @Manti_Core : Just try displaying it normally before it reaches the DAL and see what its value is. It will confirm that it is only a single character, no other values: `MessageBox.Show(employee.Grade.ToString());`.

Comment: @VisualVincent true it shows me just the character

Comment: @MetaColon A `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, not ASCII. It takes one UTF-16 code unit to form the "Z" Unicode codepoint. You can see the codepoint in this [table](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use string datatype for Grade

```
public string Grade { get; set; }
```